# Reformatting/restructuring/filtering data in existing Excel file and appending/editing to a designated format of another existing excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Excel report that I want it to be reformatted, restructured, and filtered into a specific Excel format.
The original Excel report shows repetition of 2 columns per 11 rows like the example below:

```
row1 : var1   |var2|var3   |(Empty)|var5|var6|var7|var8   |var9|(Empty)|var11|
row2 : (Empty)|var2|(Empty)|var4   |var5|var6|var7|(Empty)|var9|var10  |var11|
```

I have a designated list of `row1:var1` variables and first I need to filter the other data out.

Next I need to filter out the data that I need, which is `row1:var1`, `row2:var2`, `row1:var7`, `row2:var10`, `row1:var11`. Then I need to use these data and create them into a row and compare and fix the existing excel file with the designated format according to `row1:var1` variable.

For example, if "john" is a common person in both of the excel files(as in `row1:var1`) but if "john" in my Excel file have different properties(as in all the cell data I need except for `row1:var1`), I would like to update those properties with the properties of the reporting Excel file.

I have no clue where to start and I would greatly appreciate it if someone can help me out, even a little guidance.

Thank you ahead of the response.

Comment: The best place to start is usually the design of the output sheet. Once you have the available data in one sheet and the picture of how they will look after processing in another you can decide on the steps to take, for example filtering. So you design the output sheet for that part of the project, until you have a step small enough to be able to tackle with the macro recorder.